# How do you get the rows and the columns in the result of a query with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way with ActiveRecord to execute a custom SQL query and have it return an array of arrays where the first row is the column names and each following row is the row data?  I want to execute something like:

```
connection.select_rows_with_headers "SELECT id, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name, email FROM users"
```

And have it return:

```
[["id","name","email"],["1","Bob Johnson","bob@example.com"],["2","Joe Smith","joe@example.com"]]
```

This would allow me to print the results of the custom query in an HTML table like this:

```
<table>
  <% result.each_with_index do |r,i| %>
    <tr>
      <% r.each do |c| %>
        <% if i == 0 %>
          <th><%=h c %></th>
        <% else %>
          <td><%=h c %></td>
        <% end %> 
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Note that `select_all` doesn't work because the keys in each hash are unordered, so you've lost the ordering of the results as specified in the query.

Comment: Try `.exec_query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not EXACTLY what you're looking for, but maybe:

```
connection.execute('select * from users').all_hashes
```

and you'll get back

```
[{:id => 1, :name => 'Bob', :email => 'bob@example.com'},{:id => 1, :name => 'Joe', :email => 'joe@example.com'}]
```

and you could do:

```
results = connection.execute('select * from users').all_hashes
munged_results = []
columns = results.first.keys.map(&:to_s)
munged_results << results.first.keys.map(&:to_s)
munged_results += results.map{|r| columns.map{|c| r[c]} }
```

something like that

edit:

```
results = connection.execute('select * from users').all_hashes
munged_results = []
columns = User.column_names
munged_results << columns
munged_results += results.map{|r| columns.map{|c| r[c]} }
```

That should be ordered properly.

Beyond that there is the result object that is returned from #execute that can be interrogated for bits of information. Methods like #fetch_fields get you the fields in order  and #fetch_row will get you each row of the result set as an array (works like an iterator).

edit again:

OK, here's a good solution, modify for whatever DB you're using:

```
class Mysql::Result
  def all_arrays
    results = []
    results << fetch_fields.map{|f| f.name}

    while r = fetch_row
      results << r
    end

    results
  end
end
```

That will get them without a ton of overhead.

Use it like this:

```
connection.execute('select salt, id from users').all_arrays
```

Comment: The queries aren't always going to be SELECT *.  They may have a subset of the columns or columns based on aggregate calculations, etc.  I updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Yeah, all_arrays is exactly what I was looking for.  Wish there was something non-adapter specific, but I'm sure it's not too hard to make for for sqlite, postgres and mysql.  Thanks!

Comment: any fetch_fields equivalent for newer rails? (3.2.x ?)