# Get columns names with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to get the actual columns name with ActiveRecord?

When I call find_by_sql or select_all with a join, if there are columns with the same name, the first one get overridden:

```
select locations.*, s3_images.* from locations left join s3_images on s3_images.imageable_id = locations.id and s3_images.imageable_type = 'Location' limit 1
```

In the example above, I get the following:

```
#<Location id: 22, name: ... 
>
```

Where id is that of the last s3_image. select_rows is the only thing that worked as expected:

```
Model.connection.select_rows("SELECT id,name FROM users") => [["1","amy"],["2","bob"],["3","cam"]]
```

I need to get the field names for the rows above.
This post gets close to what I want but looks outdated (fetch_fields doesn't seem to exist anymore [How do you get the rows and the columns in the result of a query with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690248/how-do-you-get-the-rows-and-the-columns-in-the-result-of-a-query-with-activereco) )

The ActiveRecord join method creates multiple objects. I'm trying to achieve the same result "includes" would return but with a left join.

I am attempting to return a whole lot of results (and sometimes whole tables) this is why includes does not suit my needs.

Comment: You can get all columns of a ActiveRecord model by using: **Model.columns.map(&:name)**, but i am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: When I do a join, I don't know which values belong to which models. This is why I wanted to columns' names.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Active Record provides a `#column_names` method that returns an array of column names.

Usage example: `User.column_names`

Comment: for anyone who comes here in future, this method is deprecated http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @pahnin ; it would be great if you (or anybody else) can recommend alternatives

Comment: column_names() is still available for ActiveRecord classes, it has just been moved into a different module.

Comment: `ModelName.columns.map(&:name)` still works great as of June 2015.

Answer (score 21):

two options

```
Model.column_names
```

or

```
Model.columns.map(&:name)
```

Example
Model named Rabbit with columns name, age, on_facebook

```
Rabbit.column_names
Rabbit.columns.map(&:name)
```

returns

```
["id", "name", "age", "on_facebook", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is just way active record's inspect method works: it only lists the column's from the model's table. The attributes are still there though

```
record.blah
```

will return the blah attribute, even if it is from another table. You can also use

```
record.attributes
```

to get a hash with all the attributes.

However, if you have multiple columns with the same name (e.g. both tables have an id column) then active record just mashes things together, ignoring the table name.You'll have to alias the column names to make them unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried aliasing but didn't get anything different in AR's. It is always the same mashed together results. Is there any specific aliasing that AR expects?

Comment: each column name needs to be unique, e.g. select table1.*, table2.id a s t2_id, table2.name as t2_name etc. AR won't do anything clever with that but it will stop everything colliding

Comment: This means I would have to alias every single duplicate column... Very tedious :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have been wanting to do something that's more efficient for a while.

Please note that for very few results, include works just fine. The code below works better when you have a lot of columns you'd like to join.

In order to make it easier to understand the code, I worked out an easy version first and expanded on it.

First method:

```
# takes a main array of ActiveRecord::Base objects
# converts it into a hash with the key being that object's id method call
# loop through the second array (arr)
# and call lamb (a lambda { |hash, itm| ) for each item in it. Gets called on the main
# hash and each itm in the second array
# i.e: You have Users who have multiple Pets
# You can call merge(User.all, Pet.all, lambda { |hash, pet| hash[pet.owner_id].pets << pet }
def merge(mainarray, arr, lamb)
    hash = {}
    mainarray.each do |i|
      hash[i.id] = i.dup
    end

    arr.each do |i|
      lamb.call(i, hash)
    end

    return hash.values
  end
```

I then noticed that we can have "through" tables (nxm relationships)

merge_through! addresses this issue:

```
  # this works for tables that have the equivalent of
  # :through =>
  # an example would be a location with keywords
  # through locations_keywords
  #
  # the middletable should should return as id an array of the left and right ids
  # the left table is the main table
  # the lambda fn should store in the lefthash the value from the righthash
  #
  # if an array is passed instead of a lefthash or a righthash, they'll be conveniently converted
  def merge_through!(lefthash, righthash, middletable, lamb)
    if (lefthash.class == Array)
      lhash = {}
      lefthash.each do |i|
        lhash[i.id] = i.dup
      end

      lefthash = lhash
    end

    if (righthash.class == Array)
      rhash = {}
      righthash.each do |i|
        rhash[i.id] = i.dup
      end

      righthash = rhash
    end

    middletable.each do |i|
      lamb.call(lefthash, righthash, i.id[0], i.id[1])
    end

    return lefthash
  end
```

This is how I call it:

```
 lambmerge = lambda do |lhash, rhash, lid, rid| 
                         lhash[lid].keywords << rhash[rid] 
                end
    Location.merge_through!(Location.all, Keyword.all, LocationsKeyword.all, lambmerge)
```

Now for the complete method (which makes use of merge_through)

```
  # merges multiple arrays (or hashes) with the main array (or hash)
  # each arr in the arrs is a hash, each must have
  # a :value and a :proc
  # the procs will be called on values and main hash
  #
  # :middletable will merge through the middle table if provided
  # :value will contain the right table when :middletable is provided
  #
  def merge_multi!(mainarray, arrs)
    hash = {}

    if (mainarray.class == Hash)
      hash = mainarray
    elsif (mainarray.class == Array)
      mainarray.each do |i|
        hash[i.id] = i.dup
      end
    end

    arrs.each do |h|
      arr = h[:value]
      proc = h[:proc]

      if (h[:middletable])
        middletable = h[:middletable]
        merge_through!(hash, arr, middletable, proc)
      else
        arr.each do |i|
          proc.call(i, hash)
        end
      end
    end

    return hash.values
  end
```

Here's how I use my code:

```
def merge_multi_test()

    merge_multi!(Location.all,
                 [
                     # each one location has many s3_images (one to many)
                     { :value => S3Image.all,
                       :proc => lambda do |img, hash|
                          if (img.imageable_type == 'Location')
                            hash[img.imageable_id].s3_images << img
                          end
                       end
                     },

                     # each location has many LocationsKeywords. Keywords is the right table and LocationsKeyword is the middletable.
                     # (many to many) 
                     { :value => Keyword.all,
                       :middletable => LocationsKeyword.all,
                       :proc => lambda do |lhash, rhash, lid, rid|
                         lhash[lid].keywords << rhash[rid]
                       end
                     }
                 ])
  end
```

You can modify the code if you wish to lazy load attributes that are one to many (such as a City is to a Location) Basically, the code above won't work because you'll have to loop through the main hash and set the city from the second hash (There is no "city_id, location_id" table). You could reverse the City and Location to get all the locations in the city hash then extract back. I don't need that code yet so I skipped it =)